# Move Tracking Extract to Export Subfolder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, data, data-export, automationstudio

I have a data extract (Standard Tracking Extract) that I created in Email Studio under Interactions.  I built an automation that I'd like to schedule on a recurring frequency daily.  However, the default location of a data extract is that MarketingCloud drops the file in the Export folder.  Apparently it is not possible to place the extract in any other location when it is created; system default.

Given that I will have files produced each day, I would like to organize the files into a subfolder under the Export folder.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I have tried the file transfer activity, but that will not work.  Does anyone know if it is possible to use a Script activity in the automation to move the file from Export to a subfolder in that directory?  If not, is there any other possible solution to accomplish what I’m trying? Or is it impossible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create [File Locations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5) for each of those subfolders. Then in the Data Extract or File Transfer activity, you can select the file location for your subfolder.

[image: File Locations]